# Apache solr search integration at live site

Tags: 7, search

I have a Drupal site configured to use the [Apache Solr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module for searching.  I developed it using a local server on my machine.   This works fine once everything is indexed.

I need to make this live, but I have shared hosting, which doesn't support Tomcat.

What can I do in this situation?  Does the Apache Solr module support running the webserver and Solr server on different hosts?

Comment: Most shared hostings will not allow you to run solr on it, what you can do is search for a solr host for your site, and link your site to that host. in other words. your solr host could be on a different machine/host.

Comment: You mean to say...I should purchase another hosting from some other provider who support apache solr...ran that there...and link my current site to that ?

Comment: exactly. If that wont cost much ;)

Comment: @saadlulu - Can you suggest any cheap option for it ?

Comment: @RajeevK Hosting recommendations are off topic for this site.

Comment: @RajeevK  I took the liberty of doing a rewrite to make this a better fit for the site.  Please correct any technical inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a solr instance on a regular hosting service; the most of them give you a database server and Apache Server.

However, you can use a Free or Paid solutions like [OpenSolr](http://www.opensolr.com/), for example.
Once you have this configured, you just need to copy and paste the Solr URL into your Drupal Solr configuration.